# add_action in static class

Tags: plugins, actions

I want to run an action hook inside a static method.

```
Class WPUsers
{
    public static function AddUser( $data )
    {
        // add user stuff
        // return user_id
        if ( $user_id ) {
            add_action( 'admin_notice', array( $this, 'success_notice' ) );
        }
    }

    public static function success_notice()
    {
        // success notice
    }
}
```

When I run this, it gives the below error and does not run the action hook.
**"Undefined variable: this in C:\xampp\htdocs........**"

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Instead of $this use __CLASS__

Comment: `$this` refers to the current object instance. You have none, your methods are static and procedural.

Comment: so what should I do then, I used CLASS it did not work.

Comment: thank you, I figured this out, I used `__CLASS__` instead of `$this` and it worked.